# Need sql to return an array of objects not an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

For some reason my query is now returning an array of hashes when I need an array of objects.
I can't figure out what to do.

```
inbox_sql = self.mailbox.inbox.where('conversations.id IN (?)', active_conversations).reorder('').to_sql
sentbox_sql = self.mailbox.sentbox.reorder('').to_sql

sql = "#{inbox_sql} UNION #{sentbox_sql}"
conversations = Profile.connection.execute(sql)
```

When

```
self.inbox.mailbox.first.class
```

returns

```
Conversation(id: integer, subject: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

BUT

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).first.class
```

returns hash, which is problematic and ruining the rest of my code in the views.  [ Used to return a Conversation object in a less optimal way], but I need it to return a Conversation(..) object

Comment: Do you really need all the `UNION` and `to_sql` stuff ? It seems too complicated and may be rewritten with a simple where that would return Conversations. What are the relation between `self`, `mailbox` and `inbox/sentbox` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails you don't execute things, you use rails **ActiveRecord** functions.

read about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

for example:

```
Conversation.where(...)
```

will execute a sql query and will return *Conversation instances*